# How to 'summarize' variable which mixed by 'numeric' and 'character'

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

here is data.frame `data`  as below , how to  transfer it to  `wished_data`  Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(category=c('a','b','a','b','a'),
                      values=c(1,'A','2','4','B'))

#below code can't work
data %>% group_by(category ) %>% 
  summarize(sum=if_else(is.numeric(values)>0,sum(is.numeric(values)),paste0(values)))
  
#below is the wished result
wished_data <- data.frame(category=c('a','a','b','b'),
           values=c('3','B','A','4'))
```

Comment: Why is `wished_data[[4,2]]==4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing numeric and character variables in a column is not [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). Consider giving  each type their own column, for example:

```
data %>%
  mutate(letters = str_extract(values, "[A-Z]"),
         numbers = as.numeric(str_extract(values, "\\d"))) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(values = sum(numbers, na.rm = T),
            letters = na.omit(letters))

  category values letters
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  
1 a             3 B      
2 b             4 A
```

In R string math does not make sense, `"1+1"` is not `"2"`, and `is.numeric("1")` gives `FALSE`. A workaround is converting to list object, or to give each their own columns.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a separate column to group numeric values in a `category` separately from characters.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(num_check = grepl("[0-9]", values)) %>%
  group_by(category, num_check) %>%
  summarize(sum = ifelse(
    unique(num_check),
    as.character(sum(as.numeric(values))),
    unique(values)
  ), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   category num_check sum  
#>   <chr>    <lgl>     <chr>
#> 1 a        FALSE     B    
#> 2 a        TRUE      3    
#> 3 b        FALSE     A    
#> 4 b        TRUE      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of a messy answer,

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data %>% 
            filter(is.na(as.numeric(values))), 
          data %>% 
            mutate(values = as.numeric(values)) %>% 
            group_by(category) %>% 
            summarise(values = as.character(sum(values, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>% 
         arrange(category)

   category values
#1        a      B
#2        a      3
#3        b      A
#4        b      4
```